# Navigation title not appearing correctly in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a VStack wrapped around a NavigationView. I made a NavigationTitle by adding the modifier to VStack. However, my title is not appearing near the top of the screen as it should.

Here is my code:

```
  NavigationView{
        VStack{
            Image(club.image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(height: 300)
            Text(club.name)
                .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .black))
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20){
                Label(title: {
                    Text(club.league)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }, icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "location.north.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                })
                Label(title: {
                    Text(club.netWorth)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }, icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "dollarsign.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                })
            }
        }.navigationTitle(club.name)
    }
```

I have tried adding the '.navigationTitle' modifier to the NavigationView as well, but that isn't working.

Here is an image as well:
[Navigation title image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyyAG.png)

Does anybody have a solution to this?

Comment: Remove the extra `NavigationView` it looks like you have multiple. Most apps only require one. Modals are some of the few exceptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [lorem ipsum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12738750/lorem-ipsum) has mentioned. It's as simple as removing the extra NavigationView. When using a [Navigation Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink) it's assumed that it's within a NavigationView. So you only need to declare it once in the root view. If you wanted additional `NavigationLink` you'd add it without a NavigationView.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Chelsea")
                NavigationLink("Second View Link", destination: SecondView())
            }
            .navigationTitle("Chelsea")
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Second View")
        }
        .navigationTitle("Second View")
    }
}
```

[image]